# SVN code organization: How to have a filtered branch?

Tags: svn, version-control

We are using SVN branches to implement our **deployment workflow**. Development happens in `/trunk`. When we want to deploy a release, we merge everything into `/production`. Before `/production` is deployed the code is reviewed and approved. Goal of the code review is to guarantee that the code is "safe" according to certain criteria.

The SVN has lots of tools, binaries and other files that are required for development (i.e. test code, build tools, ...). They are not required for production, though. **It is impossible to review all of those miscellaneous artifacts (especially opaque binaries).** On the other hand, nothing that is unreviewed may enter production.

We'd like to have `/production` be a filtered view of `/trunk` that only contains whitelisted files and folders. **Is there a practical way to have such a filtered branch?** Or any other practical way to fulfill the needs of the code review process that we have?

Comment: It's not clear to me why this would be necessary.  If the files aren't changed then the SVN database is optimized such that they're just pointers from the branch to the original, so they're not taking up any extra space.  What's the problem that needs to be solved here?  If the files haven't changed, there's nothing to review.  If they have changed, shouldn't they be reviewed by some measure?

Comment: The files do change and it is impossible to say with certainty that these (opaque, unreviewable) files do not affect production. They might contain malicious code. This is a high-security environment. We'd like to exclude stuff like test code. We don't even allow external DLLs in production (like NUnit). But we allow them for development.

Comment: I imagine the simplest approach would be to filter them out in the deployment strategy, not in the source control.  Not everything that's in source control needs to be deployed, and indeed you've indicated that these files aren't deployed (if I understand correctly).  There should really be a step between grabbing from source control and pushing to any environment (production or otherwise) during which the source is published into a deployment package of some sort.  If the files aren't part of the release build and aren't in the deployment package, is that sufficient?

Comment: @David a good point. But how could correctness be established at review time? We'd have to trust the build process to not let suspicious files through.

Comment: Not to sound snarky, but if you don't trust the build process then how can you trust what you're putting in Production at all?  It sounds like the review step might be focusing on the wrong things.  Review the source from which the product is built, build the product, release the product.  Reviewing the build output doesn't seem productive because *any* compiled code would be un-reviewable at that point.

Comment: @David none of the critical files are ever executed according to the development team. We are looking for a stronger assurance than their word, though. The reviewing party is the customer. He needs a simple way to tell that these "dangerous files" cannot affect production. Telling him to just ignore those files is no longer satisfactory to him.

Comment: @usr: How are you reviewing binary files at all? If the customer doesn't trust the devs, you've probably got a problem svn can't handle. That's a management task then.

Comment: @PMF We don't have external binary files. The project does not require (non-Microsoft) libraries. I understand that this is a very special situation. Tens of millions of customer data are at stake. We are protecting the data from attackers and insiders.

Comment: ??? You're using svn to store production data? Ithink I still don't understand the exact problem. Can you give an example of how your repository looks like and what you want to be in production? (Structure, types of files...)

Comment: @PMF we are not storing production data there, but we are storing files that will end up on production machines. Concrete example: NUnit.dll. This file is not code-reviewable because its contents are opaque. Of course the app will never use this dll, but that is not apparent to the customer at review time. I'm looking for a way to exclude such files to make it 100% transparent that they do not cause harm.

Comment: It seems you need some script to perform that task. We have a separate build step that copies the trunk/bin folder (where the build output ends up) to the distribution share. This step is controlled by an extra configuration file that says which of the files in bin really need distributing, and which ones don't.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. Feel free to add answers for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read about [SVN Externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html). As of SVN version 1.6, it is possible to define individual files as svn-externals.

Essentially, it provides you a property list where you can specify what files (and their revisions) are checked out when a certain SVN location is checked out. Usually this is used to *add* additional files to a checkout, but you can adopt it to check out *only* specific files that you want to whitelist.

Although internally this is managed through *SVN properties*, you can import/export these through a text document, which is much easier to maintain. Unfortunately, there is no wildcard filtering of any sort (but you can specify SVN paths, not just individual files), so for your purposes, you would need to list every single file/directory that you want in your "production" branch in this SVN Externals properties file.

Comment: Is this functionally identical to performing a selective checkout with SVN? As I understand it I can checkout an arbitrary sub-tree.